# Add shadow (recessed text effect) to Cocoa label without degrading text rendering quality

Tags: cocoa, antialiasing, shadow, nstextfield

I'd like to create statusbar with text effect like in Safari or iTunes, i.e. recessed text.

[image: example]

However, if I simply add shadow in Interface Builder using Core Animation panel, OS X's worst text rendering kicks in:

[image: wheres my subpixel]

What's the trick to get recessed text on a label *and* keep proper subpixel rendering?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a built-in way to do this:

```
[[yourTextField cell] setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleRaised];
```

Comment: I don't think so, this is handled internally by the system. You'd need to write your own drawing code to change it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a cheap old trick: You draw the text in white at an offset and then draw the black text on top of it.

There is a hook for shadows in the text-drawing system, NSAttributedString's NSShadowAttributeName. But testing this out, it appears to kill the subpixel antialiasing as well.

Comment: Isn't there a better solution though? One of the numerous OS X text APIs must do it properly...

I don't want to add another label, as this will be harder maintain and will probably be annoying for Voice Over users.

Comment: The answer dealt with drawing extra text, not necessarily adding an extra label. You could create a custom subclass of NSTextField with custom drawing code. Then, you only need one label.

Comment: You don't need to do any of this, NSCell handles it for you. See my answer.

Comment: @irsk: Good point. I'm leaving mine since it works in any version of OS X while `setBackgroundStyle:` wasn't introduced until Leopard.